# Template Does Not Display Object

Tags: meteor

*I am brand new to Meteor, so apologies for the newbie question.  Note I am using CoffeeScript.*

I create a new collection above the server and client "ifs" as follows:

```
Trivia = new Meteor.Collection("trivia")
```

On Startup, I insert some docs into the collection under if Meteor.isServer.  One example here:

```
Meteor.startup () ->
        Trivia.remove({})
        Trivia.insert({question: "Who Played Ethan Hunt in Mission Impossible?", choices: ["Tom Cruise", "Matt Damon", "Liam Neeson", "Edward Norton"], answer: "Tom Cruise", used: false})
```

On the HTML page, I have a "trivia" template with {{ask}} inside.

```
<body>
  {{> trivia}}
</body>

<template name="trivia">
  <p class="label label-info">Movie Trivia:</p>
  <h3>{{ask}}</h3>
</template>
```

Here is my code within the .isClient

```
if Meteor.isClient
    Template.trivia.ask = () ->
        Trivia.findOne({used: false})
```

As it is, I get back [object Object] inside my h3 tag in the HTML.

I am trying to just get back the question text, but I get a blank page if I use the following code:

```
Template.trivia.ask = () ->
    Trivia.findOne({used: false}).question
```

If I run **Trivia.findOne({used: false}).question** inside the console, I get what I was looking for, which is: "Who Played Ethan Hunt in Mission Impossible?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Tom Cruise! jokes

The query is returning an object containing your document:

```
{
  question: "Who Played Ethan Hunt in Mission Impossible?", 
  choices: ["Tom Cruise", "Matt Damon", "Liam Neeson", "Edward Norton"], 
  answer: "Tom Cruise", 
  used: false
}
```

So the above is what is given to handlebars, but you want the question so you should use:

```
<h3>{{ask.question}}</h3>
```

Regarding the blank page when you use `Trivia.findOne({used: false}).question`. This is because when meteor initially loads on the browser, the local collections are empty until it fetches them from the server. So at some point, for a very short time, the query will return nothing so you just need to handle the case when `findOne({used:false})` has no results. The page goes blank when runs into the exception.

Comment: Super helpful response Akshat.  Thank you.  Works brilliantly!